# How to disable jobs killing when leaving the terminal

Tags: bash, kill

When I leave a terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and there are jobs in the background I get **There are stopped jobs** for the first time, but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> again, the jobs get killed.

Can I disable the latter feature somehow, so that bash **wouldn't** allow me to leave a terminal at all if there are stopped jobs?

Comment: Have you tried [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)? You can detach a console and even keep foreground-processes running.

Even though this is not the answer to you question, it might be helpful.

Comment: can you start the job and add ampersand at the end of the command? `tcpdump -w out.pcap &` this should run even after exiting shell - it works for me

Comment: I am sorry, I was misanderstood. I was saying about processes stopped with ctrl-D, not the ones started in background.

Answer (score 2):

run :

```
nohup <command> &
```

nohup is "no hangup"

After seeing your updated question, then the above isn't going to work for you. You could try running the job as usual from the command line, then doing a `CTRL-Z` (which will *pause* the running program), then issuing a `bg %1` (%1 being the last job you created).  This will effectively let your program continue in the background. Now you have to detach the job from your session by running `disown -h`.  This will instruct the shell to dis-associate the running job from your session and prevent any SIGHUP's being sent to it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way of stopping bash from killing jobs on the second `exit` but to help I have added a job count to my prompt as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646917/show-job-count-in-bash-prompt-only-if-nonzero which might make me less likely to mash ctrl-D